# Setting value of lookup Field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model

Every article about how to do this is slightly different and can't seem to figure this out.

I have two lookup fields which are both present on my `Listitem`. I have reference to the list item here.

The lookup field values are exactly the same (they are different lists they points to). So if `Human Resources Document Category` has `Test1` as this value, it also exists in the lookup list for the field `HR Document Category`.

What I want to do is through CSOM update the field so if `Human Resources Document Category` says `Test1` I want to `HR Document Category` to show `Test1` as well.
[image]

```
foreach (var listitem in listItemCollection)
{
     //var boxedListItem = (SPListItem)listitem;
     context.Load(listitem, f=>f.DisplayName, f=>f.FieldValuesAsText);
     context.ExecuteQuery();

     //get reference to lookup field value
     var humanResourceDocCategory = "Human_x0020_Resources_x0020_Document_x0020_Category";
     FieldLookupValue originalCategoryValue = listitem[humanResourceDocCategory] as FieldLookupValue;

     //get ref to HR Document Category
     var hrDocCategory = "HR_x0020_Document_x0020_Category";
     listitem[hrDocCategory] = originalCategoryValue.LookupId;
     //listitem
     //listitem.ParseAndSetFieldValue(hrDocCategory, originalCategoryValue.Id);

     listitem.Update();
     context.ExecuteQuery();
     Console.WriteLine();

  }
```

This doesn't seem to work. If I do sometrhing like `listitem[hrDocCategory] = listitem[humanResourceDocCategory]` then, it doesn't add the value!!

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's according to what I understand,

**Scenario:**

You need same value in both **Human Resources Document Category** and **HR Document Category** columns. As both are lookup columns and both are pointing to different lists for that.

**Possible solution:**

- If **Human Resources Document Category** has `test1` value, then
  fetch that value (test1) by firing caml query in list which is pointed in **HR Document Category** column as a reference.
- Get its **id** and assign it to `listitem[hrDocCategory]`.

Hope this will help you.